# Wuxt (Nuxt/Vue) sort items in v-for based on parent/child

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to sort the items in v-for loop which gets comments from a WP db, but the db stores comments with sequential IDs, and since there are replies to some of the Comments their order is messed up.

I want to have the correct order which is denoted by comment.parent property, and with the order that the comment which is the child should be under the parent. The conditional class "commentreplied" should be enough for indenting the div to make it visually composed.

This is my code so far:

```
    <div v-for="comment in commentArray" :key="comment.id" :class="{'commentreplied' : comment.parent !== 0 }" class="commentblock">
        <img :src="comment.author_avatar_urls['96']" />
        <h3>{{ comment.author_name }}</h3>
        <div class="comment-body" v-html="comment.content.rendered"></div>
    </div>
```

The Comments JSON in pastebin
https://pastebin.com/vpgy1btw

Comment: Maby add an example of the response from the server so we can see the structure of it?

Comment: Sure @DannyThunder I included the pastebin with the test data. Thanks!

Comment: I see the fields, now what is the expected output here? Is the parent supposed to match the ID field? Can you sort the pastebin data to show the result?

Comment: Every array has a parameter `parent` which references the id of the post to which the comment is the child. I made the pastebin with comments here: https://pastebin.com/mdP88zMV